# Use domain model as a document in RavenDb?

Tags: c#, nosql, domain-driven-design, ravendb

I'm thinking of using my domain models (DDD) as documents in RavenDb. Is that a bad idea?

If not, I'm using id classes (like `TodoListId`) which contains the id (in ravens case `todolists/3` etc). How can I tell Raven/JSON.NET to use them as the id?

```
public class TodoListId
{
    public class TodoListId(string id)
    {
        //validate the id and set internal var
    }

    //override ToString to return the id
}

public class TodoList
{
    public TodoList(TodoListId id)
    {}

    public TodoListId Id{get;set;}
    public TodoListId Parent {get;set;}
    public string SomeBasicProperty {get;set;}
}
```

Also, when I'm using nhibernate I usually set all setters to protected to make sure that the domain models are used properly. Is that possible with the RavenDb client too? Or wont serialization work then?

`todoList.Id.ToString()` would return `todolists/1`.

Comment: Why not just put the Id property right in the class? Or have your domain entities derive from EntityBase, and put the Id there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the protected setters, yes, that will work.
Regarding the TodoListId, you need to provide an `ITypeConverter` implementation and register that with the `DocumentStore.Conventions.IdentityTypeConvertors` to make RavenDB understand how to translate between your Id type and the id string.

Comment: The oracle has spoken.  It shall be.

Comment: Will Raven still be able to generate the id?

Comment: jgauffin, yes, it should be able to do that, yes.